# Parse.com as CodeIgniter Backend

Tags: codeigniter, parse-platform

I have googled and searched SO for the title above but didn't get much help. I am new on backend side (usually working on frontend), and my boss suddenly want to use Parse for our backend. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use it with CodeIgniter? A friend of mine suggested to discard CodeIgniter if I use Parse.
2. If it is possible, do I just need to make a call to the API through CI's controller to post/get data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the head of all the pages that require Parse:

```
 <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js"></script>
```

In your code, before using any Parse classes, add the initialization call with your Application ID and JavaScript key:

```
Parse.initialize("XVRsi5WgBbUrEXNc6zfGnvNbSFDmWD9sSda2X3iP", "XeuUDEzRJGOS5NtpBdeeswdRWDu3olmuMJvO9yN2");
```

If you are converting an existing Backbone application to use Parse, read the conversion instructions.

https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#convert